# What is the significance of using a bracket on the node of the linked list in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, brackets

In the below code there is a node pointer `naya` in the mn function. In the `if` condition first time the `naya` pointer is pointing to the null and we are trying to access its data. If we try to do the same code without the brackets around the `naya` pointer, then it gives error such as:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void mn(Node*, Node**)’:
prog.cpp:66:50: error: request for member ‘data’ in ‘* naya’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
     if(*naya == NULL || temp -> data <= *naya -> data)
                                             ^*
```

But when we are using the brackets its' working fine. Why?

Below is the whole code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Node {
 public:
  int data;
  Node* next = NULL;
  Node(int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
};

void mn(Node* temp, Node** naya) {
  Node* current;

  if (*naya == NULL || temp->data <= (*naya)->data) {
    temp->next = *naya;
    *naya = temp;
  } else {
    current = *naya;
    while (current->next != NULL && (current->next->data < temp->data)) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    temp->next = current->next;
    current->next = temp;
  }
}
Node* isort(Node* head) {
  Node* temp = head;
  Node* naya = NULL;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    Node* nex1 = temp->next;
    mn(temp, &naya);
    temp = nex1;
  }
  return naya;
}
void printll(Node* head) {
  Node* temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    cout << temp->data;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
int main() {
  Node *head = NULL, *temp = NULL;
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    Node* newnode = new Node(x);
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = newnode;
      temp = head;
    } else {
      temp->next = newnode;
      temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
  head = isort(head);
  printll(head);
}
```

Comment: Tip: Express things like `current->next` without the spaces. Spaces make it significantly harder to parse when reading.

Comment: `->` has higher precedence than `*`. `*naya -> data` is equivalent to `*(naya -> data)` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Also in C++ use `nullptr` in preference to `NULL` and use initializer lists, like `Node(int x) : data(x), next(nullptr) { };`

Comment: Unrelated, but good to know: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it has to be written this way is because of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), which decides which operations are executed using which operands. You can see from that link that 'member access' or `->` is bound before 'Indirection (dereference)' or `*a` by default. By enclosing the dereference operation in brackets you can specify that you want it to be bound first before the member access.

To make this more concrete, in your example `naya` is a pointer to a pointer. C++ by default tries to bind the operands for the member access operation first (i.e. `naya->data`). If we were to add brackets to make the order explicit here, it would look like this:

```
*(naya->data)
```

This has the effect of dereferencing `naya` and then looking for a `data` member variable in the dereferenced object. The dereferenced object is pointer though, so it has no `data` member. If it didn't error out there, it would go on to try and dereference the value of the data member (the `*` part of the expression).

When you put `(*naya)->data`, you are telling C++ that it should dereference `naya` with `*` specifically, not `(naya->data)` as it does by default. `(*naya)` is a pointer to a Node object, so `->` will successfully find the data member.

Comment: "operator precedence" means the way that operands are associated with operators;  not the order of evaluation.  This is a common misconception, e.g. in `f() + g() * h()`, the `*` has higher precedence but the `f()` might be evaluated before the others .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @M.M! I'll update the answer.